# Ubuntu 16.04 sftp and vscode ssh not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, ubuntu-16.04, sftp, mobaxterm

I use MobaXterm on my windows PC to connect to an Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

I worked well until recently I found that SFTP is not working, so my MobaXterm sftp pane is disappear.

To make sure that is not MobaXterm issue, I also download FileZilla to test SFTP, not working either.

Also, I tried to use VSCode on my windows PC with extension "Remote-SSH" to connect to my Ubuntu machine, but it keeps showing this error:

[image]

I am not sure if these connection problems I mentioned above are came from after

1. I installed zsh on my Ubuntu machine,
2. I installed XRDP but uninstall after.

Any help I would be very appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your zsh configuration, does anything output right after you login or open a terminal?

I had a similar issue where rsync would complain about a dirty terminal (I forget the exact message, but basically rsync didn't see what it was expecting to see in the remote connection).  It turned out, the problem was the `fortune` command I had added to my `.bashrc`; it was printing out a fortune message at the start of every SSH connection, regardless of if it was an interactive session or not.

In my case, I added the below snippet to the top of my `.bashrc`, which cleared up the problem:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
```